# NFT mint call reverted while testing

Tags: web3js, gas, nft, hardhat, mint

So I have gotten to the point in my NFT project where I am testing the minting from the website that I setup to mint from. I deployed to Rinkeby, and when I go to mint NFTs on my website, I get the error "Contract Execution reverted." Then when I go to Etherscan it tells me that `Value transfer did not complete from a contract execution reverted` I will attach my mint function here.

```
function whitelistMint(
    uint256 amount,
    bytes32[] calldata merkleProof
  ) public payable nonReentrant {
    address sender = _msgSender();

    require(wlIsActive, "Whitelist sale is not open");
    require(_verify(merkleProof, sender, maxWhitelistMint), "You are not whitelisted");
    require(amount <= maxWhitelistMint - _alreadyMinted[sender], "Insufficient mints left");
    require(msg.value == mintPrice * amount, "Incorrect payable amount");

    _alreadyMinted[sender] += amount;
    _internalMint(sender, amount);
  }
```

Could this be an issue with gas estimation? Or is there a problem with my mint function? The weird part is that I can mint directly from Etherscan.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [value transfer did not complete most likely as a result of a revert opcode](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/45132/value-transfer-did-not-complete-most-likely-as-a-result-of-a-revert-opcode)

Comment: No, the function is already defined as payable.\

Comment: Am I missing something from that?

Comment: @GrayBlanchard Can you share the failed transaction hash? There isn't enough information to determine the exact cause.

Comment: @Ismael https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x7e28a054e04b3c95e0253ebcc16b0a73b90714ae60508d15ceb3bb69cffd6bef

Comment: I do find it interesting that the transaction cancels at 22,742 gas units everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The failed transaction calls the function with id `0xba41b0c6` which refers to the function

```
mint(uint256 amount, bytes32[] merkleProof)
```

But there isn't a function `mint` with that signature in the verified contract. There's a `mint(uint256 amount)` and `whitelistMint(uint256 amount, bytes32[] merkleProof)`.

The contract doesn't have a fallback function so the call fails because there's nothing to execute.

You have to modify the code to call `whitelistMint` instead of `mint`.

Comment: Ok ,so this is an error in my front-end code. I am using a no code website builder, and it is a pain to use with JavaScript. I was using my contract ABI to call the whitelistMint function, but I guess it was still looking for mint().